# C++ CLI: cliext::vector<T> as return type of public class function?

Tags: vector, c++-cli, cliext

I have next class in C++ CLI:

```
   public ref class MyClass
   {
        public:
           MyClass(void);
           virtual bool Init();

           cliext::vector<int>^ ListOfNumbers();
   };
```

I would like to recive vector of int from public fucntion.

Here is impl:

```
cliext::vector<int>^ MyClass::ListOfNumbers()
{
    cliext::vector<int>^ devs = gcnew cliext::vector<int>();
    devs->push_back(1);
    return devs;
}
```

My problem is that I got next warning:

> warning C4677: 'ListOfNumbers': signature of non-private member
>   contains assembly private type 'cliext::vector<_Value_t>'

Could someone tell me the reason? Could I receive collection of items from public function C++ CLI class?

Comment: Seems like I should use List<T> from System and do not ask such stupid questions... =)

Comment: Using STL/CLR is never not [a mistake](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24206/A-look-at-STL-CLR-performance-for-linear-container).  Yes, do use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I don't know it, but I wouldn't be suprised if all CLI **template** instantiations were private and not exposable through the public assembly interface. You know, the **template** types generated by C++/CLI aren't really helpful when talking to other .Net assemblies, and "talking to other .Net" is just what C++/CLI is for.

"Native C++ templates" if (I can call them like that) are usable and accessible **only** from C++ side. CLR runtime cannot operate on them in general, as the C++ part of the compiler is not able to generate proper type description for these. (*)

For creating .Net interfaces, use .Net BCL types. Use **generics** instead of templates. So, look at types like `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`. They can safely be exposed in public interfaces. (**)

Remember that C++/CLI is a **mixture** of native C++ and .Net. You get easy access to both worlds, but those worlds doesn't really like being mixed ;)

EDIT:
(*) As JochenKalmbach reminded, it applies to the "native" templates. Microsoft has prepared a special STL version that implements **some** of the core collection interfaces, hence its `vector` actually implements `System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable`. That `vector` here is still subject to native restriction and cannot be published through asembly interface directly as itself (as `vector<>`). However, the latter type (`IEnumerable`) is completely normal CLR type and can be exposed. So, try for example:

```
System::Collections:::Generic::ICollection<int>^ MyClass::ListOfNumbers()
{
    cliext::vector<int>^ devs = gcnew cliext::vector<int>();
    devs->push_back(1);
    return devs;
}
```

It probably will compile - but I've not checked.

Comment: "CLR runtime cannot operate on them.": This is not true. As you can see, the "cliext::vector" is derived from ICollection and IEnumerable! Therefor :NET can work with this classes directly! The only point is that it cannot be directly used accross assembly boundaries; but you can cast it to the .NET interfaces and then it works!

Comment: @JochenKalmbach That's a good point. It's not really the same thing, though: other .NET assemblies can work with *instances of* those classes, so long as they don't need to know about those classes themselves. But it does open up another approach to solving the problem: declare the function as returning one of those interfaces, instead of the concrete type.

Comment: That's true, I'll correct the wording in a minute. I meant that CLR runtime cannot operate on **typical** templates, like those from standard std, boost, or those manually crafted. Templates provided by Microsoft library are carefully tailored to implement the bridging interfaces. But that's just a clever trick, not possible in general usage.

Comment: @hvd: That is exactly what 'dram_machine' suggested ;) See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385659

Comment: @JochenKalmbach dream_machine didn't suggest that, he suggested to just ignore the warning (not realising it's an error) or convert to `List<T>`. You did suggest using an interface, and I missed your answer. :)

Comment: @hvd: Yes... but the link he provided did suggest it ;) But of course, you are right... only the link contains the correct solution. His suggestion was wrong ;)

Comment: @hvd: But the way: It even works with generics, so you should replace the "ICollection" in your example with `System::Collections::Generic::ICollection<int>^`

Comment: @JochenKalmbach That's quetzalcoatl's example, but agreed :)

Comment: Corrected, many thanks again. And I've just noticed I forgot the `^`, eh, getting older, not better..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Now use the correct namespace `*Generic*::ICollection<int>^` then it will compile ;)

Comment: @JochenKalmbach: Please, just don't tell me I've also got a space between gc and new ;)))

Answer (score 2):

cliext::vector is not intended to be used accross assembly boundaries. It can only be used inside your C++/CLI project. So add a "private:" and return an "IEnumerable" in the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return collection. check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385659.aspx

Although if you want to use this method in .NET framework or Native C++ you have to convert this collection to compatible collection of that particular language.

Comment: The warning cannot be ignored. If you take a look at your link, you MUST declare the cliext types as "private" (then the warning disapears) and just return the according .NET generic type...