# Pass STL/C++/CLI container to .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vector, stl, c++-cli

I have a vector of cv::Point2f. What I want to to is to pass this vector to C# from c++/CLI.

Since I can't just store cv::Point2f into std::vector, I used cliext::vector.
Then, I'm not sure how to get it from C#...

This is my code from c++/CLI:

**points** is a vector of cv::Point2f who is already defined and initialized somewhere else.

In C++/CLI,

```
cliext::vector<System::Drawing::Point> ManagedCPP::Points::get() {
    cliext::vector<System::Drawing::Point> cliext_points;

    for (auto &point : points) {
      cliext_points.push_back(System::Drawing::Point(points.x, points.y));
    }
    return corners;
}
```

In C#,

```
ManagedCPP mcpp = new ManagedCPP();
??? = mcpp.get_Points();  // what should be ???
```

or is there any type-casting needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673874/c-cli-cliextvectort-as-return-type-of-public-class-function

Comment: Nah, title is ok, I am already sleeping:). Sorry, do not mind me:)

Comment: Please don't tag C++/CLI with C++, thanks (cc @Atomic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot return a type cliext::vector< T > for it is not publicly declared.  However you can cast it to IEnumerable< T >:

```
   IEnumerable<System::Drawing::Point>^ ManagedCPP::Points::get() {

     auto corners = gcnew cliext::vector<ystem::Drawing::Point>();
      for (auto &point : points) {
         corners->push_back(System::Drawing::Point(points.x, points.y));
     }
     return corners;
  }
```

Alternatively you can return a standard .NET container (List or array).

```
array<System::Drawing::Point>^ ManagedCPP::Points::get() {

    auto list = gcnew List<System::Drawing::Point>(points.size());
    for(auto & point: points) {
       list->Add(System::Drawing::Point(point.x, point.y));
    }

    return list->ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I think I was perhaps wrong as the vector, STL/C++ is probably the vector:  **points**. But I am not sure completely, as it is not defined in the question.